# Force HTTPS in a JavaEE app using Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am developing a JavaEE applicaction using Glassfish as server. I would like to force http connections to https. I have added to following code to web.xml, but when I run the application I have a message in the browser saying that Connection was interrupted. What am I doing wrong? If this is not the right forum to ask this question let me know. Thanks in advance.

Web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AllPages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Glassfish logs

Context path from ServletContext: /Project-war differs from path from bundle: Project-war
Información:   JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check, context(Project/Project-war_war)- permission(("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "" "GET"))